# MIDL not allowing pointers?

Tags: midl

I am attempting create a C++ projection in C# using MIDL.  According to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/rpc/reference-pointers MIDL allows pointers so in my .idl file I have defined as such:

```
namespace TestComponent {
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass TestRuntimeClass {
        void TestFunction([in, out, ref] char *pChar);
    }
}
```

However, when this file compiles I get the error `[msg] syntax error [context]: expecting an identifier near "*"`. Any ideas?